# Serializable Exception while retrieving Taxonomy term in Event Receiver

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I am trying to get value from `Managed Metadata Column` in an `Item Added` event receiver.

```
SPListItem item = list.Items.GetItemById(itemId);
TaxonomyFieldValueCollection str = item["colName"] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection;
```

While trying to get the value, I am getting this exception on `TaxonomyFieldValueCollection` line mentioned above:

`Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue' in Assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' is not marked as serializable.`

Can anybody tell what can be the possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a look at the below post, it contains how to update Taxonomy term programatically.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/03eb0260-e69a-4aba-99e7-c41d8ea6654d/how-to-update-a-document-field-using-taxonomy-term-programatically?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious